# How to correctly delete a user (and get the user to autmatically logoff) in ASP.NET using Identity Server

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, cookies, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I'm using IdentityServer 4 but I think this question applies to ASP.Net identity in general.

We are considering to adapt an external (WinForms) tool to automatically delete (and later also create and manage) users. This tool has direct access to the IdentityServer database.

Is it as simple as deleting the record in the `AspNetUsers` table (and any additional records in profile/preferences/settings/roles tables) or is it more involved? Would we have to cycle the IdentityServer application pool as well?

In addition, if the user is logged in and actively busy on the Identity Server website, will the cookies be invalid as soon as the user tries to load a page with the `[Authorize]` attribute (after the record is deleted)?

We'll also have to notify all sites that make use of the tokens coming from the IdentityServer, but it looks like there is an existing solution for that (Backchannel Logout) which looks quite clumsy at first glance... It looks like a request is sent to the client to clear the cookies... I hope I'm seriously misunderstanding something here...

Comment: I think there is nothing wrong with this logic. The user has logged in to the website at this time, and you delete the information in the database. If you do not tell the client to clear the cookie, the user will still retain the original permission to access, and the permission will not be cleared until the next login, instead of refreshing in real time .

Comment: @Chen If you lay off employees, they keep the keys to the office and you do not change the lock?

Comment: For traceability, I think its better to deactivate users and physically delete the user from the database.... :-)https://udidahan.com/2009/09/01/dont-delete-just-dont/

Comment: @ToreNestenius Unfortunately the `AspNetUsers` table is generated by code provided by Microsoft, and a user can delete itself with the standard "scaffolding code"... I added a column with an employee ID which is used and logged in the rest of the application. The user record is only used for the authentication code so it is is easily disposable. By the way, they use a string as primary key and strings for guids etc.. Wasn't expecting the whole concept to be as bad as the db schema, but it looks like I should never have blindly taken the default authentication concepts for granted.

Comment: Sorry @Louis Somers, you may have misunderstood me, I mean there is no problem with the logic of the `existing solution` you mentioned. When you fire an employee, the employee keeps the key and you need to notify someone else to replace the door lock (send a request to the client to clear the cookie).